# Deploying code without disrupting testers

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm attempting to find the best practice for deploying code from a TFS Development branch, to a Test branch without disrupting users who're testing.

We currently have continuous integration, wherein we are able to merge the code from Dev to Test, then fire off the separate Test - Nightly build, to have those changes committed to the build server and thus on the test site.

Are there practices/tools available to allow users to not be impacted by a deployment? I don't have any experience with Git, which I've seen a few times on Google.

Ideally we could do a deployment, the users wouldn't feel it, then if there was an issue with the code that was introduced we could quickly flip it back to it's previous state, rather than perform a roll back, rebuild etc.

I'm sure I'm explaining something that already exists I just don't know what it is.

Comment: This is not something that "TFS" or "Git" can do for you. You would have to build an app with an Architecture to allow Zero downtime installations. If this is a Web Site, it should be easy. If it's a desktop application, you're going to find it more challenging

Comment: Yes, this would be for an internal site.

Comment: The MSBuild/TFS Publish Settings should be able to deploy a website without any real noticeable downtime. There is no automatic rollback process. But you could deploy the files from the previous builds drop folder.

Comment: I've heard that there is a way to perhaps have two different live branches, one (Live1) with the code being used, one (Live2) with a copy of said code with the new changesets. The person in charge of deploying flips the switch for users from Live1 to Live2. Then if there's a bug that is causing down time, we immediately swap back to Live1.

Comment: Running 2 branches like that in TFVC isn't be easy. Either way, there's no magic button to deploy the branch without running a build in TFS. You could re-build to a label and deploy that.

Comment: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html